# finite dimensional but incomplete norm space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Every finite dimensional normed space (over the field $R$ 0r $C$) is complete.
But this result is not true in general for any arbitrary field, for example $Q$ (set of rational numbers) is one dimensional norm space (with field = $Q$) but is not complete, so for arbitrary field is there any concrete result regarding completeness?

Comment: Well, the field itself ought to be complete ...

Comment: Ok. If field is complete then every finite dimensional normed space is complete

Comment: You need an ordered field to formulate the triangle inequality.

Comment: @Jochen When you say that do you want the norm to map into the field or into the reals? Because I can't see how an ordering of the field is necessary for the triangle inequality, which just says that the norm $\|\cdot\|:V\to\Bbb R_{≥0}$ is subadditive. If the field is not ordered you can't pull out positive numbers though.

Comment: I think you should specify the context you are interested in here. What kind of norms do you allow? Are they to be real-valued? How do you feel about valuations? That said, I think that most likely in every reasonable sense, a finite-dimensional space over a complete field is complete. This is because a finite dimensional space should be topologically equivalent to a finite product of the base field and completeness should be a topological property, preserved by finite products (or even *full* infinite products).

Comment: You also have to give homogeneity a sense: What should $\|\lambda x\|=|\lambda| \|x\|$ mean if $\lambda$ and $\|x\|$ belong to different fields?

Comment: $\lambda$ and $||x||$ belong to same field. Answer to my question lies in this sentence I think "A finite-dimensional space over a complete field is complete"